# Forming Matrix from text file matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a text file with all numeric data with each line as specified below

> label index1:value1 index2:value2 . . . index8:value8

example line :

```
1 1:0.731641 2:0.0445045 3:0.959925 4:1 6:0.366283 7:0.304412 8:0.616054
```

A row can have a missing value on any index, How can I form a matrix of 9 columns with this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `textscan` with the `%d:%f` format specifier to get this information. Here is a full example of how that could be done.

```
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');

%// Get the label of the first line
label = fscanf(fid, '%d', 1);

%// Initialize matrix to hold the result
%// If you know what the maximum label will be you can make this the right size
m = zeros(0,9);

%// Row counter
row = 1;

%// Loop until we hit the end of the file
while ~feof(fid)
    %// Look for a number followed by a colon and another number
    data = textscan(fid, '%d:%f');

    values = data{2};
    columns = data{1}(1:numel(values));

    %// Fill the matrix at the columns that we loaded using the label as the row
    m(row, columns) = values;

    %// The next label was automatically picked up because it matched %d

    row = row + 1;
end

fclose(fid);
```

I tested this on the following input:

```
1 1:0.73  2:0.04  3:0.95  4:1  6:0.36  7:0.30  8:0.61
2 2:0.99  2:0.45  5:0.99  4:2  7:0.5  9:10
3 1:-2  9:12
```

And was able to generate the following matrix

```
m =
    0.73   0.04   0.95     1      0   0.36   0.3   0.61    0
       0   0.45      0     2   0.99      0   0.5      0   10
      -2      0      0     0      0      0     0      0   12
```

**Update**

If you have a very large matrix and it is sparsely populated, you can instead use something like the following to create a sparse matrix from the data.

```
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');

%// Get the label of the first line
label = fscanf(fid, '%d', 1);

%// Initialize rows/cols/values array
[rows, cols, vals] = deal([]);

%// Row counter
row = 1;

%// Loop until we hit the end of the file
while ~feof(fid)
    %// Look for a number followed by a colon and another number
    data = textscan(fid, '%d:%f');
    columns = data{1}(1:numel(data{2}));

    %// Append data to rows/cols/vals arrays
    vals = cat(1, vals(:), data{2});
    cols = cat(1, cols(:), double(columns(:)));
    rows = cat(1, rows(:), row + zeros(size(columns(:))));

    %// The next label was automatically picked up because it matched %d

    row = row + 1;  
end

fclose(fid);

%// Create the sparse matrix
m = sparse(rows, cols, vals);
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it give error out of memory error with 2000 rows file .

Comment: What are the maximum values for the `label` and the maximum `index`?

Comment: @Dharmendra I suspect that your matrix is a sparse matrix. Try the code in the "Update" section of my answer

Comment: @Dharmendra Also are the labels *actually* the row numbers?

Comment: labels are 1 or -1 and all values are between (0,1)

Comment: @Dharmendra So do you want each row to be it's own row in the matrix then?